# Row in UIPicker not returning the correct value

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am using Swift to write an iPhone app and I have a problem with UIPickerview.

```
class LanguageChangeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var changeLanguagePicker: UIPickerView!

var pickerData = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(row, forKey: "which")
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    whichLanguageChosen = row
    println(whichLanguageChosen)
}

override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()
changeLanguagePicker.dataSource = self
changeLanguagePicker.delegate = self
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }
```

}

the problem is in whichLanguageChosen, this println gives correct value, but when I press "back" after positioning in that row, it returns weird values: 0 - 0, 1 -> 5, 2-6, ... 6-2, 7-7.. In addition, when I do not click "back" after the first time I chose a line, i.e. when I scroll twice through the picker, it returns the correct value. What could that be?

EDIT: 
This might be helpful:

In my firstViewController (the one that back sends to), I have

```
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("which") != nil) {
    whichLanguageChosen = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("which") as Int
    }
```

I put that inside so that he remembers when I restart the app on which language it was. When I comment this line then the values I get are correct, obviously I do not understand NSUserDefaults enough to see why is that the wrong line, and moreover, where does the weird pattern come from (+- 4)?

In addition, is there another way for instruct my code to save the value of whichLanguageChosen?

Comment: can you attach an output image what do you mean by back ?

Comment: Apologies for not explaining more. I have a segue to the previous page saying "back". The whichLanguagechosen is a global variable that should change with that UIPicker, for instance it is 2 at the begining then I use segue to move to another controller where I have this UIpicker, choose, say, 1, this println confirms that is 1, return to the previous controller and then the println says it's 5 and not 1..

Comment: post both of your controller's complete code. Also the values you are trying to save aren't saved because you missed one extra line of code which actually stores the data in persistant storage i.e NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()